# Push mercurial merged branch without history

Tags: mercurial, branch

Given that I have created a branch in Mercurial how can I push the resulting merge of that branch to a remote repository without the history of how I got to that merged branch result. For example.

```
[a] - [b] -----------------[k]
     \                     /
      [g] - [h] - [i] - [j]
```

[a], [b] and [k] being the 'default' branch, [g] through [j] being the feature branch. Once I merge the feature branch into the default branch how can I have just [a] - [b] - [k] change sets in the remote repository when I push? I don't want to simply not see the branch, I do not want those change sets pushed to the remote repository at all. I don't care how I got to [k], I do care what the [k] end result is though.

I am currently leaning toward the branch by cloning method but how can I accomplish this with cloning? Would there also be a way to make this work with named branches?

I have been looking for an answer to this but there is so much documentation out there it's difficult to find this needle in a haystack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of merging, you want to use [hg rebase](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension) with the [--collapse](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension#Collapsing) option.

```
hg rebase --collapse --source [g] --dest [b]
```

The rebase extension is shipped with Mercurial, you just need to [enable](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension#Configuration) it in your settings file.

p.s. If you have already committed the merge [k], you should [rollback](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#rollback) (or [strip](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Strip)) it first before rebasing.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for all the links. Now I wish I could figure out how to get TortiseHg to do that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I push the resulting merge of that branch to a remote repository without the history of how I got to that merged branch result

No ways to get stripped history for **merged** branches

Comment: In as-is form, but [Collapse extention] (http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CollapseExtension) can help